# QThreadPool::jobQueueSize() ? QThreadPool::finishedJobCount()

Tags: multithreading, qt4

Is there any way to know how many jobs it has finished executing ? e.g. why there is no method like `QThreadPool::jobQueueSize()` or `QThreadPool::finishedJobCount()` or `QThreadPool::waitingJobCount()`.

I see Nither do `QRunnable`s offer any such functionality. like `started()` or `finished()`

Should I do a Hack like. in `QRunnable::run()`

```
/**
 * Assuming _controller has a link to all the Runnables. and I've a finite number of QRunnables that I recycle in my own Way. 
 */
void MyRunnable::run(){
    mutex.lock();
    _controller->markAsStarted(this);
    mutex.unlock();
    ....
    mutex.lock();
    _controller->markAsFinished(this);
    mutex.unlock();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[QThreadPool](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qthreadpool.html) is a singleton and uses the interface implementation idiom. Which means that the actual implementation is performed by QThreadPoolPrivate class and QThreadPool is just the interface.

First alternative:
You need to patch QThreadPoolPrivate to get the methods that you want.

Next you need to patch [QThreadPool](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qthreadpool.html) to return its hidden QThreadPoolPrivate implementation
so that you can access this internal class

Second alternative :
Patch the constructor of [QThreadPool](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qthreadpool.html) to inject your own implementation that provides the methods that you need.

In both cases you need to patch Qt's source code.